# Is there a library in Python that has a full list of registered domains on the internet?

Tags: python, dns, pypi

I want to implement a program that basically detects to see if input from the user is not a genuine domain name or registered name on the ICANN.

Comment: Have you looked into a `whois` library?

Comment: how about just validating the input with regex for domain name ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a library in Python that has a full list of registered domains on the internet?

No, not in Python or any other language, and for obvious reasons (don't you think such kind of list would get misused if it existed?)

First two points:

> see if input from the user is not a genuine domain name or registered name on the ICANN.

ICANN has nothing to do here with your needs. It has no operational play in the day to day life of domain names, when they are registered or deleted. ICANN just define the list of current TLDs, that is basically topmost registries maintaining central databases with the list of domain names.

What is a "genuine" domain? But more importantly, what exactly do you need to test with domains? Is it like for people entering an email address to test if it is plausible? If so, testing the domain name is not the correct approach. But to say more really depends on your use case that you do not describe, which also makes your question offtopic as long as it has no more relationship with programming.

So just some generic ideas:

- you can use the DNS to query domain names, but this has edge cases (and you need to understand how the DNS works) among which not all really registered domain names are published, for totally normal reasons
- you can use whois, as John said, or better RDAP when it is available (at least all gTLDs); this has drawbacks too, as, without a solid library parsing the replies, you don't even have a standard way of finding out if a name does not exist, as the registries will give different free form strings for such cases; plus it is not suitable for high volume queries as it is heavily rate limited
- if you would be really interested in something closer to a list of domain names, all gTLDs are required to publish their zonefile, at least daily, which is basically the list of all resolving domains (which is a subset of the list of all registered domains, consider a few % of difference), see https://czds.icann.org/ ; some ccTLDs do it too, but each one on their own policies and rules, some have an "open data" feature that gives things similar (often with a delay) or a list of "recently" registered domain names (so if you grab that days after days at some point you have something close to the list of all domains)

Any good programming language has already polished libraries for DNS queries, whois or RDAP queries, or parsing zonefiles.